# UWP Binding property to current item of ItemsSource

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

I got the following setup for my page:

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RecentResults}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="400" ItemHeight="300" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ui:CarResultControl Result="{Binding}" Padding="0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I bind to a local property which provides my results asynchronously. This works perfectly fine.

Now my *`CarResultControl`* binds to it's local *`Result`* property (which is an `DependencyProperty`). When I specify `Result={Binding}` then the property get's updated but not as expected with the `CarResult` but `CarResultControl`. If I use `Result={Binding Path=.}` or similiar, it just doesn't update at all.

As far as I'm used to it in WPF `{Binding}` actually bound to the data object itself, not the control you´re attaching the binding to. Interesting is that IntelliSense actually shows the properties of the expected `CarResult` object when I have to choose a binding path for *Result*.

Is UWP doing it's own thing here again, am I just a fool and doing it wrong or is this really a bug? I struggled for long enough and can't find any info about it.

Comment: This actually should be working the way you expect unless you are changing the `DataContext` of the `CarResultControl`. Isn't it possible that you do something like `this.DataContext = this;` inside its constructor?

Comment: I actually do. Now it actually sets the `CarResult`. Downside is, that the bindings in the `CarResultControl` don't work anymore. That's why I bound the data context to the control itself in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

This actually should be working the way you expect unless you are changing the `DataContext` of the `CarResultControl`.

`UserControls` actually work in a bit weird way - when you set `this.DataContext = this` in the constructor, then the binding on properties will actually be relative to the `UserControl` itself.

To fix this you must make sure not to change the `DataContext` of the control itself. The easiest way is to add `x:Name` to the root `Grid` (or whatever control you have in the content of the `UserControl` and then set its `DataContext`:

```
RootGrid.DataContext = this;
```

This way you will the data context of the `RootGrid` will be set to the control itself, but the user control's properties will be bound to the data context relative to where the user control is, here to the list item.

Comment: Yeah after you told me that, I figured it out by myself. I managed to fix it by adding `x:Name` to the control itself and using the `ElementName` property on bindings. Bit messy, though, since you got to write it everywhere (gonna fix that quickly). Nontheless, is this by design? This was kinda unexpected...